# How to create a program that requires number inputs that exits after typing a non-numeric character, using getchar() and infinite loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop, getchar

An assignment asks us to create a program in C that asks for user input of only numbers, using getchar() and infinite loop with while(1), that stops after typing a non-numeric character.

This is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    while(1){
        int x = getchar();
        if (isdigit(x) == 0){
            break;  
        };
    };
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run the code and type anything, it will stop after the first attempt, no matter what I type.

Can you please find a way to correct the code above?

Comment: OT: Semicolon `;` is only needed after non-block statements. After `{}` blocks it's considered an empty statement.

Comment: As for your problem, what do you think happens with the newline that the `Enter` key is adding to the input buffer? The lesson for today: Learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. Like using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: "it will stop after the first attempt" No, it will not. Add `printf("%d\n", x);` just after `getchar` and give the input `123<enter>` and you'll see that the loop executes 4 times

Comment: In other words... the program is doing exactly what your description says. But perhaps the description is missing something like: "only numbers and newlines"

Answer (score 0):

`stdin` is, by default, line buffered meaning the input will not be received by your program till you press `<enter>`.  If you to entire newlines do something along these lines (pun):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    for(;;) {
        int x = getchar();
        if(x == '\n')
            continue;
        if (!isdigit(x))
            break;
    }
}
```